# Hexo: How to retrieve post asset folder inside a custom tag

Tags: hexo

I'm creating a custom tag to insert a more advanced image html code in a post.

I cannot find a way to refer to the post asset folder inside the custom tag.
In markdown we have the snippet {% asset_path image_name %} that retrieve the full path to a post image.
I would have the same inside custom tag js file.

I've not been able to find something useful in the hexo site documentation.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: after further analysis I've realized there is no way to refer post asset folder in a custom tag, other than passing the post asset path as a function parameter.
So the new question would be, is it possible to use the {% asset_path %} tag inside a custom tag snippet, like this {% image_p 'img_name.jpg' 'param2' 'param3' 'asset folder tag' %}?

Pietro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you make that path configurable and use something like:

```
<img src="<%- config.asset_folder_root %><%- item.image_path %>" />
```

EDIT:

If you have an asset folder for each post, you can add a custom property to your front matter. So for each `post.md`, at the beginning you would have something like:

```
title: Hello World
date: 2013/7/13 20:46:25
asset_folder: /dummy/path/to/folder
---

[... your blog post content ...]
```

And then you can reuse that access that property anywhere in your template by using `item.asset_folder`:

```
<img src="<%- item.asset_folder %><%- item.image_path %>" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've an asset folder for each post of my blog, so I need at least the title of the post (that is the same as the post asset folder). Is it possible to retrieve post title in a custom tag?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've to write a custom tag (it is a js file inside the script folder), not a template. See my edit.

Comment: I see. Yes you can pass it as parameter or have a convention of some sort for the asset folders structure. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post - but wanted to update it with a better answer. The "this" object has, among other things, a field called permalink that you can use. If you use that, you can do something like:

this.path+'cat.jpg'

https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/2305